# How to manage SEO for site with dynamic pages powered by search queries?

Tags: seo, dynamic

I have a site, which is basically a search engine. So, whenever a user inputs something, a dynamic page gets created and as soon as the user closes it, it is no longer a page. For example, the link of my pages are like:

```
www.example.com/?q=SEARCH+TERM
```

So, how should I manage SEO for my site so that the search engines can also find all these dynamic pages which at some time, had been opened by someone and didn't return any error (404, etc.).

Comment: Google has said they do not want search result pages in their index. Can't find the link right now but basically they are low quality pages that are not useful in their eyes. But if you want to take the risk you can always add them to an XML sitemap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to be incredibly difficult for you to achieve. Firstly Google awards valuable original content and penalizes sites which simply contain duplicate content from other sites. Secondly Google has started cracking down on search results pages being listed in the Google index as these results pages don't present any useful content to the end user and only require the end user to click on something else to go to the page they where looking for (http://searchengineland.com/google-warning-against-letting-your-search-results-get-indexed-10709).

You should ensure that you try and comply with the [Webmaster Guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769) that Google publishes which specifically state key to your question to avoid

- Creating pages with little or no original content
- Scraped content

Comment: So, what if I create a new page for every search result with meta keywords and description, such as, mysite.com/search_query_xx.html?

Comment: The question you have to ask is if you are adding genuine new content or if the whole purpose of the page you propose to create in your comment is to improve your search engine listing. You should be creating your site and pages for users and not for search engines.

Answer (score -1):

dynamic websites are very popular and necessary to pass information between the database and the user in the easiest way. Database driven websites often need certain information before they can return page contents: session id, cookie data, or query string. Only one page written in server side scripting (ASP) can handle thousands or millions of records separately.

Comment: While this may be true, it doesn't answer the question.